# Why my certificate status is still in pending state in aws?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, certificate, amazon-route53, aws-certificate-manager

I have created a certificate in aws using terraform with zone name "test.io" . Unfortunately i have deleted that certificate using terraform . When i try to recreate the certificate with same zone name i.e "test.io" , using this Terraform code   , CNAME record is created and certificate status is still in pending for days. And i'm able to create it with different zone name using DNS validation . Can any one suggest me.

Comment: You have to show your code that you use. Also did you check in AWS console for any error messgaes regarding the ACM?

Comment: Did you check that the certificate validation records were created under the zone (Assuming you are using Route53)?
Link for cert validation - https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/acm_certificate_validation#:~:text=each.value.zone_id%0A%7D-,resource%20%22aws_acm_certificate_validation%22%20%22example%22%20%7B,-certificate_arn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3D%20aws_acm_certificate.example

Answer (score 0):

**If** you also deleted and recreated  the hosted zone itself it got assigned different nameservers.

If you purchased the domain in AWS, it could mean that you have to update your nameservers at the registred domain. If you purchased your domain somwhere else, update the nameservers there to match the nameservers of your new hosted zone.

Not doing so will basically mean that all DNS for your domain is still being resolved by the old nameservers, that don't contain your entries any more.